# owl Carousel 2 все слайды в одном слайде

Tags: slider, owl-carousel

У меня слайды отображаются все как один большой слайд из чисел в ряд и перелистывает их сразу все. Что это за глюк?

```
<div class="first-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="first-slide">1</div>
  <div class="first-slide">2</div>
  <div class="first-slide">3</div>
  <div class="first-slide">4</div>
  <div class="first-slide">5</div>
  <div class="first-slide">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.first-slide{
     border: 3px solid green;
 }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".first-carousel").owlCarousel({

  });
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё класс owl-carousel рядом с owl-theme должен быть

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!!